# How to install bower components to multiple paths with bower-installer?

Tags: bower, bower-install

I have my *bower.json* like:

```
..
"install": {
    "base": "static/my-project/libs",
    "path": {
     ..
    "eot": "{name}/fonts",
    "otf": "{name}/fonts",
    "svg": "{name}/fonts",
    "woff": "{name/fonts",
    ..
    }
},
..
```

to install font related resources to `static/my-project/libs/bower-package-name/fonts/`.

But I found that [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) expects fonts to be placed in `bower-package-name/css/fonts`, not `bower-package-name/fonts/`.

Since I have other dependency that expects fonts to be located in `bower-package-name/fonts/`, I want to install these font related resources to multiple paths, both in `bower-package-name/fonts/` and `bower-package-name/css/fonts`.

Is there any way to install bower dependencies to multiple paths like:

```
..
"install": {
    "base": "static/my-project/libs",
    "path": {
     ..
    "eot": ["{name}/fonts", "{name}/css/fonts"],
    "otf": ["{name}/fonts", "{name}/css/fonts"],
    "svg": ["{name}/fonts", "{name}/css/fonts"],
    "woff": ["{name}/fonts", "{name}/css/fonts"],
    ..
    }
},
..
```

for example?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using grunt, you can use [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) to copy your resources to different location.

Sample grunt copy task would look like (from the above source):

```
 copy: {
  main: {
    files: [
      // includes files within path
      {expand: true, src: ['path/*'], dest: 'dest/', filter: 'isFile'},

      // includes files within path and its sub-directories
      {expand: true, src: ['path/**'], dest: 'dest/'},

      // makes all src relative to cwd
      {expand: true, cwd: 'path/', src: ['**'], dest: 'dest/'},

      // flattens results to a single level
      {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['path/**'], dest: 'dest/', filter: 'isFile'},
    ],
  },
 },
```